IC identification - Analog Devices with top marking S2 M
Please help me identify this Analog Devices IC in the MSOP-8 package. The top marking is "S2 M":


There are more characters there than just "S2" and "M". It looks as if it could be "2MS2" and "GSM" but it's faint. Would you please try for a better photograph?

Added a microscopic image, but it still looks like S2 M is all I see :(

This is an Analog Devices ADG5401. It is a Single SPST switch. I was able to find this device by going onto Analog's website and using their search tools by typing in "S2M" and then filtering by datasheets, which led me to its datasheet.


Pictures taken from aforementioned device's datasheet. I could not find another picture of the device itself. Strangely, there are no date codes on this device.
